# Shifting of cell's value to right side

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm working on kendoui. If we observe a grid then all the values are on the left side of each cell.I have a field of price and i want its value on the right side of cell.

Is it possible in kendo ui?

My code :-

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
var crudServiceBaseUrl = ${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}"+/course/,
          dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
             transport: {
                read:  {
                  url: crudServiceBaseUrl+"listAll", dataType: "json",
                                           cache: false                                                
                                       },
                                       parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                           if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                            return {models:                    
                                            kendo.stringify(options.models)};                          
   }
                                       }
                                   },
                      batch: true,
                      pageSize: 15,
                      sort: { field: "dateCreated", dir: "desc" },
                      schema: {
                      model: {
                      id: "id",
                      fields: {
                      name: { editable: false, type: "string", validation: { required:   
                      true, min: 1} },
                      type: { editable: false, type: "Type",validation: { required: true, min: 1}  
                     },                                                    
                     fee: { editable: false, type: "double",validation: { required: true, min: 1}   
          },                                                     
                     duration: { editable: false, type: "integer",                                 validation: { required: true, min: 1} },                                                                    
                     status: { editable: false, type:"Status" ,                                 validation: { required: true, min: 1} }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        navigatable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        groupable:true,
                        sortable:true,
                        selectable:true,
                        height: 300,
                        columns: [
       {field: "name",
                title:'<g:message  code="grid.billingServicesGroup.holidayName.label"  
                default="Course Name" />'},
       {field: "type.name",
               title:'<g:message code="grid.billingServicesGroup.reason.label" 
               default="Type of course" />'},
       {field: "fee",title:'<g:message
               code="grid.billingServicesGroup.code.label" 
               default="Fee" />'},
       {field: "duration",title:'
          <g:message  code="grid.billingServicesGroup.holidayDate.label"   
        default="Duration(Year)" />'}
                         ,
       {field: "status.name",title:'<g:message   
             code="grid.billingServicesGroup.status.label" default="Status" />'},
                        ],
                        editable: true,
                        change:function(e){
                            idOfData=this.select().data("id");
                            window.location.href=crudServiceBaseUrl+"show/"+idOfData;
                        },
                        saveChanges:function(){
                        },
                        remove:function(e){
                            /*alert(e.model.id.value);
                            selectedId=this.select().data("id");
                            $.ajax({
                                url:"http://localhost:8080/billing-
                       app/api/skeletonBill/"+selectedId,
                                type:"DELETE"
                                }).done(function(){alert('deleted')});*/
                        },
                        scrollable: {
                            virtual: true
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a column template to wrap the contents of all the cells in that column in for example a div-tag.
You can then use a class on the div to style the contents using CSS.

For example:

```
columns:
[{
    field:"Department",
    title:"Department",
    width:80,
    template: "<div class='foobar'>#= Department#</div>"
}]

/* CSS */
.foobar {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: In grid , field is price and i'm able to get values of price on the right side of the cell. But there is one more issue that the price value i'm getting is in the format like 600000 but i want it in the format of 6,00,000 (values separated by commas)

Comment: When you define the columns for the grid, you can use the format-option to define a format for the column.
See this link for the available formats: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/numberformatting

Comment: :Thanx for replying.
I used this code :-
     {field: "fee",title:'<g:message code="grid.billingServicesGroup.code.label" default="Fee"/>',template: "<div class='foobar'>#= fee#</div>" ,template: "#= kendo.toString(fee,\"n\") #"}

i'm getting my values in string form but again the values got shifted to left .Can't we use two template in columns .I'm very new to kendoUi .So if you help me i'vl be very thankful to you .

Comment: Aren't you defining template twice? I just realized that you can't combine the template and format options. But you can format values in your template like I do in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/3367434